# What does if [ "x" != x ] do in bash?

Tags: shell

I'm looking at the source code of virtualenv, and the activate script contains this code:

```
if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then  
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"    
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="$PS1"
    else 
    if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
        # special case for Aspen magic directories
        # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
        PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
    fi
    fi
    export PS1
fi
```

What does the line `if [ "x" != x ]` do?  x is not defined anywhere else in the script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Bash, that test is guaranteed to fail; `[ "x" != x ]` always returns a non-zero exit status (i.e. "false"), because `"x"` and `x` are both the string consisting of the single character `x`. (The quotation marks don't really have any effect in this case.)

What's more, the command `PS1="$PS1"` doesn't really do anything, either: it just sets the variable `PS1` equal to the value it already has.

I'm guessing that this script is autogenerated in some way, and that on some systems, these statements will look a bit different, and a bit less useless.

Comment: It looks like the old `[ "x$foo" != x ]` trick for checking for empty strings on old shells.

Comment: This is exactly what's going on.  The script is auto-generated, and sometimes there's a variable that gets spliced in there.  See [this](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/virtualenv_embedded/activate.sh#L59) and [this](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/virtualenv.py#L1582).  Thank you!